# How to set initial size and position of window for desktop app?

Tags: flutter

I am having an issue trying to location information on how to set the initial size and position of a Flutter desktop applications window.

Upon searching, I came across some code within the C++ files, but does anyone know if there is a way to set this from within Dart, or can it only be done in the C++ files?

Answer (score 5):

A method of modifying by platform code. You can modify these two properties through the code in this path：`windows/runner/main.cpp`.

Here is the code you want to modify：

```
Win32Window::Point origin(kFlutterWindowOriginX, kFlutterWindowOriginY);
Win32Window::Size size(kFlutterWindowWidth, kFlutterWindowHeight);
```

The initial value is here：windows/runner/window_configuration.cpp

Answer (score 1):

It can currently only be done from the platform code, because the window is created before the engine.

See [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55427) for a possible solution to this problem; if you are familiar enough with the platform toolkits on the platform(s) you are developing for, you could implement the solution described there manually in your own runner(s), by adding a custom `MethodChannel` and changing the initial creation details of the native windows.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i need arrange window on right bottom corner and i hotfix CreateAndShow(...) method(${dir project}\windows\runner\win32 window.cpp) like this:

```html
bool Win32Window::CreateAndShow(const std::wstring& title,
                                const Point& origin,
                                const Size& size) {
  Destroy();

  const wchar_t* window_class =
      WindowClassRegistrar::GetInstance()->GetWindowClass();

  const POINT target_point = {static_cast<LONG>(origin.x),
                              static_cast<LONG>(origin.y)};
  HMONITOR monitor = MonitorFromPoint(target_point, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
  UINT dpi = FlutterDesktopGetDpiForMonitor(monitor);
  double scale_factor = dpi / 96.0;
  int monitor_width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
  int monitor_hight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
   
  int new_x_position = monitor_width - size.width;
  int new_y_position = monitor_hight - size.height;
  HWND window = CreateWindow(
      window_class, title.c_str(), WS_POPUP|WS_VISIBLE|WS_SYSMENU,
      Scale(new_x_position, scale_factor), Scale(new_y_position, scale_factor),
      Scale(size.width, scale_factor), Scale(size.height, scale_factor),
      nullptr, nullptr, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), this);

  if (!window) {
    return false;
  }

  return OnCreate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This package can be helpful: [Bitsdojo Window](https://pub.dev/packages/bitsdojo_window).
It makes it easy to customize and work with your Flutter desktop app window on Windows, macOS and Linux.

[Watch the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bee2AHQpGK4) to get started.

Features of this package:

> - Custom window frame - remove standard Windows/macOS/Linux titlebar and buttons
> - Hide window on startup
> - Show/hide window
> - Move window using Flutter widget
> - Minimize/Maximize/Restore/Close window
> - Set window size, minimum size and maximum size
> - Set window position
> - Set window alignment on screen (center/topLeft/topRight/bottomLeft/bottomRight)
> - Set window title

Answer (score 1):

Example to set window position to top-right corner with 10px offset.

Modify `windows/runner/main.cpp`:

Find:

```
...
FlutterWindow window(project);
Win32Window::Point origin(10, 10);
Win32Window::Size size(1280, 720);
...
```

Change to:

```
// set window position to top-right corner
// Get the size of the primary monitor
HMONITOR primaryMonitor = ::MonitorFromWindow(nullptr, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);
MONITORINFO monitorInfo;
monitorInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);
::GetMonitorInfo(primaryMonitor, &monitorInfo);
int screenWidth = monitorInfo.rcMonitor.right - monitorInfo.rcMonitor.left;
//int screenHeight = monitorInfo.rcMonitor.bottom - monitorInfo.rcMonitor.top; // not used

// Set the origin to the top-right corner of the screen with 10 pixels padding
int xOffset = 10;
int yOffset = 10;
Win32Window::Point origin(screenWidth - 1280 - xOffset, yOffset);
//Win32Window::Point origin(10, 10); // original
```

Tested on `Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3208])`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way to do this. With this library [desktop_window](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/desktop_window), you can set the window size and so on. Examples are as follows

```html
import 'package:desktop_window/desktop_window.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('desktop_window example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("setMinWindowSize(300,400)"),
                onPressed: () async {
                  await DesktopWindow.setMinWindowSize(Size(300, 400));
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("setMaxWindowSize(800,800)"),
                onPressed: () async {
                  await DesktopWindow.setMaxWindowSize(Size(800, 800));
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the reply. Nice to see that something like this exists now. Desktop apps were a bit lacking for a while, at least until now it looks like. I had ended up using go-flutter to solve my problems at the time, then eventually modified the CPP files similar to the other reply that I see you made, but favorited this for future use. Thanks!

Comment: Desktop_Window package does not include window positioning???  Did I miss it somewhere in the code?